# Creating class for defining constants in swift

Tags: enums, swift, constants

**Note:** I want to achieve similar functionality in swift - [Where to store global constants in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12856504/217586)

I have two classes - MasterViewController and DetailViewController

I want to define an enum (refer below enum) and use its values in both classes:

```
enum Planet: Int {
    case Mercury = 1, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune
}
```

I tried to define it in MasterViewController and use it in DetailViewController like this:

```
let aPlanet = Planet.Earth
```

but compiler is complaining :(

> "Use of unresolved identifier Planet"

Generally in my objective c code I used to have a global constant file, which I used to import in app-prefix.pch file, which was making it accessible to all files within my project, but in this case I am clueless.

Comment: Are you sure your enum file is being compiled? This code works for me.

Comment: yeah.. cross verified, can you share your sample code may be I am missing some minor thing.

Comment: I literally but your first block of code into one file and the second block of code into another file in the same project and it compiled fine.

Comment: Is your enum being defined within another block, perhaps a class?

Comment: gotcha.. you caught my mistake, thnx :)

Comment: [I Think this answers your question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your enum is being defined in a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    enum Planet: Int {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You have to access it through your class:

```
var aPlanet = MyClass.Planet.Earth
```

You also want to use the `rawValue` property. You will need that to access the actual Int value:

```
var aPlanet = MyClass.Planet.Earth.rawValue
```

Comment: The function toRaw() has now been replaced by a property .rawValue in Swift 2.0.  So you would write  MyClass.Planet.Earth.rawValue now

Answer (score 22):

In swift you can declare an enum, variable or function outside of any class or function and it will be available in all your classes (globally)(without the need to import a specific file).