# How to loop through view outlets in a UIViewController with Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I'm wondering, if it's possible to loop through all the outlets of a `UIViewController` with Swift.

Specifically, I want to check if every textfield is filled by the user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what Outlet Collections are for. Drag all your textfields in the same Outlet Collection in InterfaceBuilder and create an `@IBOutlet` to that collection in your class file:

To create the outlet collection in InterfaceBuilder, ctrl-drag from the first `UITextField` to your class file in the assistant editor. Then choose *Outlet Collection*:

[image]

ctrl-drag the next `UITextField` **on that `@IBOutlet`** to add it to the collection:

[image]

Repeat that for all your textFields.

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!

func checkTextFields() {
    for textField in self.textFields {
        ... // do your checks
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create that collection? With IB?

Comment: Cool. Haven't used it this way so far.

Comment: Best Answer ever! Thanks 

Comment: Oh my god how didn't I know about this, this is amazing. Can the array be non-optional? (initialized to empty, later mutated by interface builder?)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to manually do it, or add them to array and loop through that array or you can loop through all subviews of your view and check if it's textfield.

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        if textField.text == "" {
            // textfield is empty
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception at if let textField = view as? UITextField { from type EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: @twofish187 You should checkout "zisoft" answer. His answer is much better than mine to achieve what you want.

Comment: Nitpick, but you should use `textField.text.isEmpty` instead of `== ""`