# Array of IBOutlets in Swift

Tags: swift

I have code like

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countryField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
```

How can i put all this items to array so i can access each of them in a loop?

Comment: What you want to do by accessing in the loop?

Comment: i have function that change border styles and other design things for UI elements

Comment: This is exactly what outlet collections are for. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167294/how-to-loop-through-outlets-of-a-uiviewcontroller-with-swift/29167651#29167651) on how to create them.

Comment: thank you! it really can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countryField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!

...

let array = [emailField, countryField, cityField]
```

Have a look at the [documentation on collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

edit: you can split the declaration/init of that array

```
// outside any method
var array = [UITextField]?

// in viewDidLoad
self.array = [emailField, countryField, cityField]
```

Comment: thanks it works if i put this code in ViewDidLoad. in other case i have an error that my class doesn't have member called 'emailField'