# Xcode how to combine UI buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

i'm making a custom keyboard and wanna add shadow to buttons.
so added some code(keys.layer~~) in viewDidLoad()

but i can't set multiple button to one IBOutlet
what i want is all keys have 'keys(IBOutlet)' as value(?)
is it possible? if it's not, any other thing is fine :)
help!

this is my code (pls ignore next keyboard button)

```
@IBAction func keys(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBOutlet weak var keys: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadInterface()
    keys.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    keys.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    keys.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0)
    keys.layer.masksToBounds = false
    keys.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    keys.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702043/can-i-change-the-properties-of-all-the-buttons-in-my-swift-app)..It may help

Comment: It is not possible to assign an IBOutlet to more than one Interface Object. It's a unique Identifier for a reason. In your situation I would suggest creating a subclass of UIButton suited for your needs.

Comment: @Gokul thanks it just magically worked!

Comment: @MauriceA. thanks!

Comment: You can assign multiple buttons from IB to IBOutletCollection of UIButton type. And then in loop you can modify them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `UIButton` extension like this and used with all the object of your custom keyboard `Button`

```
extension UIButton {

    func setShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method with your button object like this way

```
self.nextKeyboardButton.setShadow()
```

**Edit:**

If you want to access multiple `Button` object with same object you can create an `Array` of `UIButton`, and store all the Outlet `Button` inside that array.

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()
```

Comment: could you explain more? where should i add these code?

Comment: You can declare this extension in your current viewController file, but outside the `class` definition, not inside the `class`.

Comment: unfortunately i coudlnt adapt your answer :c i'm kinda swift newbie so need really deep long explanation ;-;

Comment: but thanks! for trying to help :)  i'll try later again when i get used to using swift more :))!!

Comment: Have you work in objective c, in objective c you can create category, in  swift extension is equivalent to category of objective c.

Comment: Are you getting what i am saying?

Comment: ah no i don't know objective c :e only know java, c , python ;-;

Comment: @YuminHwang If you search on google abt swift extension you will get idea what i have done.