# Swift 2.0 calling a struct function from the outside

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm new to Swift 2.0 so this might be a stupid question.
But I have:

```
struct Geometry {
static let Pi : Double = 3.14159265358979323846 

func get_angle(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2:Int) -> Double { 
...
func get_angle(point1 : CGPoint , point2 : CGPoint) -> Double {
```

I can access Pi by doing "Geometry.Pi" and it works just fine.
But for some reason I can't access the get_angle functions. 
I have tried "Geometry.get_angle(x1, y1: y1, x2: x2, y2: y2)" but then it complains about "extra argument 'y1' in call"
I have tried to remove all the function variable names by adding _ before the declaration of the function like so:

```
func get_angle( x1: Int, _  y1: Int, _ x2: Int, _  y2:Int) -> Double {
```

and call it like: " Geometry.get_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2) " 
but then it complains about "Cannot invoke 'get_angle' with an argument list of type ('Int' , 'Int', 'Int', 'Int')"
Why can't I do that? That's kinda the idea..
And strangely when I start to type "Geometry.get_an" the suggestion box appears and it looks wierd.. I have a photo here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaiUu.jpg If someone want to take a look. It gives me the option : Geometry.get_angle(Geometry), but Geometry isn't the variable type.

What I essentially want to do is put a number of global functions and global variables in a "constant" / "common" - file like you would in other languages..
I know that every function is basically a global function as long as it's not marked as private. 
I used this:
[Global constants file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift)
as a reference when I created Geometry..

Can anyone help me make a constants/common-file in swift 2.0 containing variables and functions?

Edit:
Just to clarify, if I make a variable of Geometry I can access the function just fine, but that's not what I want. I want global functions. 
Also, I tried moving them out of the struct, but that same errors appear, "Cannot invoke 'get_angle' with an argument list of type ('Int' , 'Int', 'Int', 'Int')"

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that there is a predefined constant `M_PI`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the function `static`:

```
struct Geometry {
    static let Pi : Double = 3.14159265358979323846

    static func get_angle(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2:Int) -> Double {
        return 1
    }
}
```

When function isn't static, you can call it like this:

```
Geometry().get_angle( ... )
```

...but this creates a new `Geometry` structure, which is not needed in your case.

Comment: Don't I feel stupid right now...
I knew I had to make the variables static, but never reflected over it on the functions. 
Thanks man :)
There is no such thing as a static struct are there?

Comment: @Skrutten you're welcome. As far as I know, swift doesn't allow creating static structs.

Comment: An enum with no cases can be a nice way to group things together (because it's impossible to create an instance).