# Colors that will be used throughout an app or a class

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I'm trying to improve my object oriented skills and I'm always debating if a class is needed or not.

I have a set of UIColors that I'm constantly using throughout my app in different ViewControllers, I originally started by adding them as constant globals as follow...

```
import UIKit
// Global COLORS
let myBlueColor = UIColor(red: 62.0/255, green: 174.0/255, blue: 206.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
// more global colors here...
class ViewController1{
   // using my global color
   myButton.layer.borderColor = myBlueColor.CGColor
}


// other viewController
import UIKit
class ViewController2{
   // using my global color again
   myButton2.layer.borderColor = myBlueColor.CGColor
}
```

But then I decided to created a class to force myself to think in more oriented way like so...

**Color Class**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Color {

    var myBlueColor:UIColor{
        get{
          return UIColor(red: 62.0/255, green: 174.0/255, blue: 206.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    var myLightGrayColor:UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor(red: 249.0/255, green: 249.0/255, blue: 249.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    var myGreenColor:UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor(red: 110.0/255, green: 186.0/255, blue: 64.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    var myRedColor:UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor(red: 247.0/255, green: 118.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    var myYellowColor:UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor(red: 255.0/255, green: 190.0/255, blue: 106.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController1{

   private var myColor = Color()

   // some other code here...

   myButton.layer.borderColor = myBlueColor.CGColor
}
```

**Other View Controller**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController1{

   private var myColor = Color()

   // some other code here...

   myButton2.layer.borderColor = myBlueColor.CGColor
}
```

Is my object oriented a better approach? Ok let me rephrase this, is this even how you would do it in a more object oriented way?

I don't know but my Color class looks weird by just using getters (computed properties).

Any suggestions to improve my code.

EDIT: Not a duplicate because I was interested on improving my object oriented example more than knowing if globals were ok to use.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global constants file in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely a good idea, but you can probably make it even more clear by just extending UIColor and making those all class functions, exactly the same way as the built-in `UIColor.whiteColor()`, etc.

You can do that like this:

```
    extension UIColor {

    class func peachColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 100.00 / 100.00, green: 92.9 / 100.0, blue: 65.9 / 100.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    ...
   }
```

Then, anywhere in your app, you can say `UIColor.peachColor()` and it'll work perfectly.  These class extensions are a clean way to do it, and it'll allow you to avoid putting a `var myColor = Color()` in each view controller.

Comment: Best and easiest implementation

Comment: Wow, when I started reading the Swift documentation I actually skip the Extensions section thinking that it was something that I would never use or at least not often but it is a VERY cool feature. Thanks a lot for the tip. For those that have never used extensions, here is what I did. `1. Created a new swift file and named it UIColor 2. Added the color function as described by @creeperspeak 3. Used your custom color as UIColor.myCustomColor()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encapsulate your Colors in a class, and they will not change, the best way to do so in an OOP environment is by using `public static final` variables.

(My Swift is very rusty at best so this may be incorrect syntax but it should be clear nonetheless.)

```
final struct MyColors {
    public static final blue:UIColor = UIColor(red: 62.0/255, green: 174.0/255, blue: 206.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    // etc
}
```

You can then reference the value by using `MyColors.blue` wherever you want, and that will refer to the single defined `UIColor` object.

Comment: I really like this approach too. I don't think `final` can be used in structs though. `import UIKit
final class Colors {
    static let blue:UIColor = UIColor(red: 62.0/255, green: 174.0/255, blue: 206.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
}` Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're trying to theme your app globally with colors, you ought to look into Apple's Appearance API, `UIAppearance`.

For example, to set the default color of all UINavigationBars in your app, you would call:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = myColor
```

You can also set other appearance properties such as background images

For more info, see:

http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/
https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521