# enabling button in swift code

Tags: ios, swift, save, boolean, didset

I begin swift and i'm making an app ( a little game).
The buttons of levels 2,... are not enabled because the user dont yet win the level 1 when the user install the application. then I want these buttons enabled everytime the user won the level. I wrote this in a file:

```
class levelList: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var blvl1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var blvl2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var blvl3: UIButton!

    var lvlWon1: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            blvl2?.enabled = lvlWon1

        }
    }

    var lvlWon2: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            blvl3?.enabled = lvlWon2
        }
    }
    let lvl1Default = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let lvl2Default = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if (lvl1Default.objectForKey("lvlWon1") != nil){
            lvl1Default.setBool(true, forKey: "lvlWon1")
            lvlWon1 = lvl1Default.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool!
        }
        else{
            lvl1Default.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon1")
            lvlWon1 = lvl1Default.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool!
        }

        //
        if (lvl2Default.objectForKey("lvlWon2") != nil){
            lvl2Default.setBool(true, forKey: "lvlWon2")
            lvlWon2 = lvl2Default.valueForKey("lvlWon2") as! Bool!
        }
        else{
            lvl2Default.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon2")
            lvlWon2 = lvl2Default.valueForKey("lvlWon2") as! Bool!
        }

    }
}
```

and this in an other file:

class lvl1: UIViewController {

```
var levelList = levelList()
@IBOutlet var bNext: UIButton!
@IBAction func nextlvl(sender: UIButton) {
    levelList.lvlWon1 = true
    levelList.lvlWon1 = levelList.lvl1Default.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool!
    let lvl1Default = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    lvl1Default.setValue(listeNiveaux.lvlWon1, forKey:"lvlWon1")
    lvl1Default.synchronize()
}
```

//my problem is that all work finely when I wrote:

```
var lvlWon1: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        blvl2?.enabled = lvlWon1

    }
}
```

so when i won the `lvl 1`, the `level2 button` is enabled, but when i add

```
var lvlWon2: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        blvl3?.enabled = lvlWon2
    }
}
```

when I win the `level1`, the `blvl2` and the `blvl3` are enabled, I don't know why

I think it's because i save the data of all `blvl` but i'm not sure. 
thanks in advance and really sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: Check in storyboard, whether all buttons are disabled during initialization.

Comment: they all are disabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

 @IBOutlet weak var startSecondLevelButton: UIButton!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.checkLevelsStatuses()
    }

 func checkLevelsStatuses() {

startSecondLevelButton.enabled = false

if let lvlWon1 = defaults.objectForKey("lvlWon1") as? Bool {
    // if true - level finished
    if (lvlWon1) {
        startSecondLevelButton.enabled = true
    }
}else {
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon1")
}

if let lvlWon2 = defaults.objectForKey("lvlWon2") as? Bool {

} else {
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon2")
}
```

}

that was because the viewDidLoad was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are calling `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` twice, in order to fix it you could:

1. Create a new variable named `defaults` and store the user defaults instance, so that this `let lvl1Default = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   let lvl2Default = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` becomes `let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`
2. Use that new variable replacing the previous `lvl1Default` and `lvl2Default` on `viewDidLoad` (and do not forget to call super)

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if (defaults.objectForKey("lvlWon1") != nil){
       defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "lvlWon1")
       lvlWon1 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool
   }
   else{
       defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon1")
       lvlWon1 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool
   }

   //
   if (defaults.objectForKey("lvlWon2") != nil){
       defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "lvlWon2")
       lvlWon2 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon2") as! Bool
   }
   else{
       defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon2")
       lvlWon2 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon2") as! Bool
   }        
   }
   ```

Edit after 2016-08-10 comment:
On my first attempt to provide an answer to your problem, I tried to isolate the problem and I succesfully managed to recreate it without considering the code on the `lvl1 class`. Since this did not solved your issue, I made a second attempt taking the `nextlvl` function in consideration.

On this function, there is another `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` call. The first thing I would do is to make the 'defaults' constant (explained previously) as a global variable so that you can access it everywhere. (in case you need more info about this, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift))
Another thing I noticed is the call to `synchronize()` which is deprecated.

So, after moving the defaults constant to somewhere global, I *think* what you meant to do on the `nextlvl` function should be:

```
@IBAction func nextlvl(sender: UIButton) {
    lvlWon1 = true
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "lvlWon1");
}
```

Edit 2:
As a side note:
When you are casting `lvlWon2 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon2") as! Bool!` you do not need to place `!` in the type, as in `as! Bool!` you just need `as! Bool`

`Bool` is a boolean type that cannot be null whereas `Bool!` means a boolean type that is implicitly unwrapped and `Bool?` means a boolean type needs to be unwrapped.

If you wish to read more about wrappers, check [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) reference

You can also use `defaults.boolForKey("lvlWon2")` which gives you the result as a Bool type and avoid the casting.

Comment: i replaced all lvl1Deafault and lvl2Default by defaults ..
but when win the level 1, blvl1,blvl2 and blvl3 are enabled. I dont want blvl3 is enabled because "i dont won yet the level2".

Comment: @Matt Jacquet This steps solved the problem on a test I did, however I placed the `lvlWon1 = true` logic on the `levelList` view controller. If this did not fix the issue, maybe the problem it is on the `nextlvl` function but I do not quite understand it

Comment: i really don't understand. i replaced all `lvlDefault` by `defaults` in levelList file and lvl1 file but the blvl3 still enabled when i finish lvl 1 .
i gave you all my code about these functions ..

Comment: i just understad, you said "i placed `lvlWon1 = true` logic on the levelList viewController" you mean `blvl1`  enabled?

Comment: before seeing your answer, i noticed all problems come from the code of viewDidLoad. 
i think it's because i wrote `}else
{
 defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "lvlWon1")
    lvlWon1 = defaults.valueForKey("lvlWon1") as! Bool
}` like when  `defaults == nil`  , it  equal to false..
does it change your answer?