# How to get reference of AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

My problem is i've constants class which is used in almost each classes in application so i've created its object in AppDelegate n through it want to access them.i don't want create object of constants every where each time.what will be the best approach please advice.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
 public var constants = Constants()
//created object once in app delegate
}

class Utility
{
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate //getting     null here
let constants =  delegate. constants
}`
```

Comment: `UIApplicationDelegate` already an unique instance. Do not ever create its copy. Just use its reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift)

Comment: Search SO before adding duplicate questions

Comment: @Vinodh - My problem is i've constants class which is used in almost each classes in application so i've created its object in AppDelegate n through it want to access them.i don't want create object of constants every where each time.what will be the best approach please advice.

         class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
     
   public var constants = Constants()
//created object once in app delegate

}

class Utility
{
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate //getting null here
let constants =  delegate. constants
}

Comment: i know but the above code is not good way to create constant. If you dealing Swift create struct and declare all yours constants there please use SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/26252377/1142743 for more details

Answer (score 1):

This should work to create an object to AppDelegate:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

You may want to create a singleton class instead.

```
class MySingleton : NSObject
{
  class var sharedInstance :MySingleton
  {
    struct Singleton
    {
        static let instance = MySingleton()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
  }

  final let myVar = "String"
}
```

And then access the properties by creating an object:

```
let appSingleton = MySingleton.sharedInstance
appSingleton.myVar
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @NitishaSharma please check my answer because you should probably refrain from using a singleton for your usecase

Comment: @igor I think this is a better way to create a singlton if you want to use one: `final class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton()
        return instance
    }()
    
    private init() {
      //make it private so nobody can initialise the Singleton from outside
    }
}`

Comment: @igor even shorter: `final class Singleton { static let sharedInstance = Singleton()  private init() { //make it private so nobody can initialise the Singleton from outside } }`

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi. Perhaps, you are right. I used some reference material on how to create singletons in Swift and the above code works fine in my application. But I am not arguing, may be there are other (better) ways to create them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use a singleton because you are just using the class for strings. Instead you should probably go for something like this:

```
struct LocalizationConstants {
    static let settings = NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: "")
    static let main = NSLocalizedString("Main", comment: "")
    static let someString = "value"
}
```